# Why in C++11 we move from one function in vector::resize to 2 version?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I'm asking this because im developing a class library.
(As i can see in cplusplus.com) in C++98 we had only one version from the [`std::vector::resize`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/) funcion:

```
void resize (size_type n, value_type val = value_type());
```

this way the function works if you want to specify the second argument or not. But in C++11 they change it to 2 different version:

```
void resize (size_type n);
void resize (size_type n, const value_type& val);
```

Is any special reason for this?

Comment: It probably had something to do with different implementations when specifying the value. I skimmed some changes from C++03 to C++11 and there could be a few reasons such as [initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Initializer_lists). I don't really have the expertise to explain this though. It could also simply be a design choice. There are different conventions and maybe they found the C++11 version better

Comment: @Havenard, That's value-initialization since `value_type` is a type name.

Comment: I suspect this has to do with removing the need for copy support in the element type when using `vec.resize(n)` (especially since move-only types such as `unique_ptr` came into existence), but that's just a guess. There ought to be an old proposal out there somewhere.

Comment: You might want the `language-lawyer` tag.  An issue with default parameters is that they get "baked" into the callsite.  Not sure if that was a consideration.  With move semantics, a by-value field is a data sink, which works for either rvalue or lvalue arguments.

Comment: Interestingly `std::string` had separate overloads before C++11 already.

Comment: @chris I guess you're right, and as it turns out you can set it to be a function, which is really weird, I thought you couldn't. In C you can't.

Comment: An advantage of having an overload instead of a default argument is the ability to have a function pointer to the defaulted variant. I doubt that's very typical use case for a non-static member function though.

Comment: It might be a design  choice, the c++ commitee choose Overloads over Default parameters, both have their own advantages and disvantages, here is a article explain it.https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/08/07/should-i-use-overloads-or-default-parameters/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For [`std::vector::resize`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize), before C++11, the default argument of `val` is always value-initialized, the appended elements are copied from it, as the effect they're value-initialized too. Since C++11 this could be avoided by providing a custom Allocator.

> 1. additional [default-inserted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/DefaultInsertable) elements are appended (since C++11)

(emphasis mine)

> By default, this will call placement-new, as by `::new((void*)p) T()` (that is, value-initialize the object pointed to by p). **If value-initialization is undesirable, for example, if the object is of non-class type and zeroing out is not needed, it can be avoided by providing a custom Allocator::construct**.

Comment: Ad actually, a `value_type` may not have a defaul initialization